# Как правильно прописать условия нахождения веб-элемента на странице?

Tags: java, selenium

В приложение передаются: хост, логин,пароль юзера, а также xpath-ы полей ввода, кнопки  submit и кнопки log out. Хочу сделать следующее. Программа, получив данные открывает браузер по введенному хосту, заполняет форму и кликает на кнопку входа(это получилось). Дальше 2 варианта: 1. если логин и пароль неверные, то запускается 2 такой же тест, который вводит другие логин и пароль. 2. происходит авторизация и для выполнения остальных кейсов нужно разлогиниться, чтобы вернуться к форме. 
То есть  как я вижу,необходимо условие, которое проверяет по xpath, есть ли кнопка log out на текущей странице и если мы авторизировались находит и нажмает. А если нет- крутит тесты дальше на текущей странице. Проблема в построении этого  самого условия. Вот мой код:

```
public void test() throws NoSuchElementException {
        System.out.println("Starting test " + new Object(){}.getClass().getEnclosingMethod().getName());
        driver.get(host);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(htmlLoginFieldXpath)).sendKeys(userLogin);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(htmlPassFieldXpath)).sendKeys(userPassword);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(htmlButtonLogOnXpath)).click();
        if(driver.findElement(By.xpath(htmlButtonLogOutXpath)).isDisplayed()) driver.findElement(By.xpath(htmlButtonLogOutXpath)).click();
        else System.out.println("Ending test " + new Object(){}.getClass().getEnclosingMethod().getName());
    }
```

Я думал, что булевый метод isDisplayed  покажет есть ли кнопка log out на странице, однако этот if кидает исключение(в данном случае я указал неверный xpath и авторизации пользователя не было): `Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"dfghf"}`

Что-то я делаю не так. Подскажите пожалуйста в чем ошибка, или может есть какой-то другой способ реализовать эту часть алгоритма?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Для выполнения остальных кейсов* следует максимально очищаться от последствий предыдущего теста, т.е. либо перезапускать браузер (с новой директорией профиля), либо хотя бы чистить cookies/localstorage, и логиниться заново. Для проверки того, что можно успешно выполнять различные действия в рамках одной сессии, следует выделить отдельный тест.

Comment: если я вас правильно понял, то средствами селениума нельзя организовать проверку- залогинился ли тест,или нет?
не совсем понял 2 предложение. что нужно проверять в рамках 1 сессии? что я подряд могу перебрать разные случаи заполнения формы без переоткрывания браузера перед каждым тестом?

Comment: Все можно. Но седует решать проблемы по мере их возникновения. Проблема разлогина исчезнет, если придерживаться базового правила -- перезапускать браузер.

Answer (score 2):

> Я думал, что булевый метод isDisplayed покажет есть ли кнопка log out на странице, однако этот if кидает исключение(в данном случае я указал неверный xpath и авторизации пользователя не было): Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"dfghf"}

Действительно, если этого элемента нет на форме (а если Вы не залогинились этого элемента и правда нет на странице), то выкинет исключение и тут есть два варианта:

1. Если вы не залогинились появляется ли что-то типо сообщения (Введен неверный логин или пароль)? Если да, то я бы осуществлял обратную проверку.

   if(появляется сообщение "неверный логин и пароль"){
   логинимся еще раз с другими
   }else{
   считаем, что авторизация выполнена и гоним следующие кейсы
   }
2. Т.к. мы знаем, что элемент "htmlButtonLogOutXpath" может быть не найден и у нас упадет исключение, мы можем отловить это исключение с помощью try..catch

Статейка на хабре [try… catch VS if…else. Что, когда и почему?](https://habrahabr.ru/post/21376/)

Comment: я понял вашу идею. и я пытался сделать 2 пункт. каждоый тест-кейс пробрасывает исключение throws NoSuchElementException и обрабатываю я их в мейне блоками try catch. но проблема в том, что он кидает исключение и тормозит, вместо того, чтобы после catch идти дальше..

Answer (score 1):

Можно разлогиниться посредством перегрузки страницы каждый раз после неверного ввода логина/пароля. То есть: тест с неверным паролем -> рефреш -> тест с неверным паролем -> рефреш -> тест с верным паролем.

```
@After
    public void ref()
    {
        driver.navigate().refresh();
    }`
```